# how to remove java System.out.println from ant script

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant

how to remove java System.out.println from ant script?
(when we compile the code from ant we should remove the existing java class system.out.println & compiled classes should not have the Sys.out.println)

Comment: You could run a search and replace, but I dont think this is a good approach. It is better to transform all the permanent printlns into logger calls, then you can dynamically turn them on and off.

Comment: Your question is not clear if you want to remove the println code using ant, or, remove the output from println when running ant. Which operation are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: basically we have java classes which contains lot of System.out.println ,(may be developers added for their debug purposes) but our requirement is ,in compiled classes should not have any sysout,we build our project using ANT scripts ,So when ant compile the java files we need to remove all sysout and compiled classes should not have any sysout. basically when  classes are running in production, should not print any values ,added previously for debug purposes.

Comment: we want to remove the all println code using ant,

Answer (score 1):

In build.xml file, preparation phase, before the mkdir commands,
provide:

```
<javac srcdir="exe" includes="SysOutRemove.java"/>
<java fork="true" classname="SysOutRemove" dir="exe" failonerror="true"/>
```

where SysOutRemove.java is in the exe package of your project.

SysOutRemove.java should iterate through the list of directories and files in them, store the contents of each file to a reader or something, find  sysout statements and replace.

Answer (score 1):

We can use this in the ant file.

```html
<replaceregexp match="System.out.println(.*);" replace="" flags="g" byline="true">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java"/>
</replaceregexp>
```